# using GDB and dealing with breakpoint detection

Tags: linux, gdb, anti-debugging

I am trying to solve a reverse engineering challenge using using `gdb`. I can run the program inside it but when I set a breakpoint at `main` then I get

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

Setting it at something even earlier like `_init` (there are two BTW) also was not very fruitful, could it be that the program might be corrupting itself at some point that I didn't catch? Have a look at the `backtrace` for that matter:

```
#0  0x47048474 in ?? ()
#1  0x0804864a in __handle_global_ctors ()
#2  0x080488c5 in __do_global_ctors_aux ()
#3  0x08048349 in _init ()
```

Now I tried to statically decompile it using a simple recursive traversal disassembler (not IDA) but I couldn't find any traces of `CC` (INT 3) so I guess another layer of obfuscation has been added.

I also tried `record` with no success:

```
Breakpoint 5, 0x0804833a in _init ()
(gdb) record
(gdb) c
Continuing.
(null)Process record: failed to record execution log.
```

Oh and I couldn't find the hex string "47048474" either.

**Any more ideas what can help in such a situation? Maybe detecting the self-modification?**

Comment: Did you try to use hardware breakpoints (hbreak gdb command) ?

Comment: Good idea! But sadly it says: "No hardware breakpoint support in the target." :/
(x86 executable on x86_64, file says ```ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.4.1, not stripped```)

Comment: Oops, as mentioned at http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11225/using-gdb-and-dealing-with-breakpoint-detection the prog simply has to be started first for ```hbreak``` to work. Finally I can continue.

Comment: What challenge is it? Can you link it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just to clarify what is already present in the comments:

`gdb`'s `break` will place an ordinary breakpoint, which works by taking the in-memory image of the process and swapping its original instruction for a specific interrupt instruction. If I understand correctly, `hbreak` tells the OS to monitor every instruction an compare the address of current instruction to the address of breakpoint (i.e. no modification of the in-memory image). However, the number of hardware breakpoints available at a time is limited.

To place a hardware breakpoint with `hbreak`, your program must be already running with `gdb`'s `run`. To achieve that, you should place an ordinary breakpoint somewhere at the very beginning (let's say, `_start` function), successfully break there, place a hardware breakpoint and then remove the original ordinary breakpoint.

Comment: Is the OS really the one doing the monitoring? I thought this is where the hardware assistance comes into play.